# Directory Separators Ignored on Inserting into mySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have been trying to  insert a directory Path into a mySQL table (reportPath column). The inserting works OK but the directory separator is ignored on insert. E.g A path of D:\public_html\Testman\config is inserted as D:public_htmlTestmanconfig. What am I missing?

Below is my code

```
            <?php
                    include "config.php"  ;
                    $dir = "csvreports";
                    $files = scandir($dir);
                    $fLocation=dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;  

                    foreach ($files as $key => $value)
                    {
                     if (substr($value, -4) == ".CSV" )
                        {        
                       mysql_query("INSERT INTO tableReports (reportPath, reportName) VALUES('$fLocation.$value','$value')");
                       }
                    }
            ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to escape the slashes:

```
$sql = sprintf("INSERT INTO tableReports (reportPath, reportName) VALUES('%s','%s')", 
           mysql_real_escape_string($fLocation.$value), 
           mysql_real_escape_string($value)
);
mysql_query($sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

Escape the data before inserting it into the database: [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)

```
mysql_query("
    INSERT INTO tableReports (reportPath, reportName) 
    VALUES(
        '". mysql_real_escape_string($fLocation.$value) ."',
        '". mysql_real_escape_string($value) ."'
    )
");
```

Answer (score 0):

When using Windows, the `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` is set to \ (backslash). But backslash is a special character in PHP, which causes PHP to interpret the next subsequent character as a special character (a character with another meaning). So you *can* use `addslashes()` to escape the backslash characters.

However, you'd better use `mysql_real_escape_string()`.